# Parameter splitting

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, parameter

I have a bash script that is a simple wrapper around another process:

```
$ cat ~/bin/s3cmd
#!/bin/sh
trickle -u 80 ~/bin/s3cmd.py $*
$
```

This works great when the parameters don't contain spaces. However, it seems to fail whenever the parameters passed to the outer `s3cmd` script contain spaces, even if those are escaped on the command line.

How do I whitespace-proof this, such that each single parameter is passed on properly to `s3cmd.py`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `"$@"`.

```
#!/bin/sh
trickle -u 80 ~/bin/s3cmd.py "$@"
```

There is no functional difference between `$*` and `$@` is when undergoing implicit word splitting (almost always when unquoted). When quoted, however, `$*` is a single string separated by the first character of `IFS`, and `"$@"` is a real array (what you want).

```
$ set foo bar baz
$ IFS=c
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
foo
bar
baz
$ printf '%s\n' "$*"
foocbarcbaz
```

Comment: Note that there can be differences between $* unquoted and $@ unquoted under some circumstances with some shells. See for instance `set a b; IFS=; a=$@; b=$*; echo "$a,$b"` in bash or AT&T ksh. Also note that in the Bourne shell (but who cares about the Bourne shell nowadays) SPC is used to separate items in "$*", not the first character of $IFS.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Perhaps I should have said "when undergoing implicit word splitting" rather than "when unquoted".

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use $@ instead of $* and quote it:

```
trickle -u 80 ~/bin/s3cmd.py "$@"
```

See also the `Special Parameters` section in the bash manpage.